# Hibernate parent-child @OneToMany relationship with default Eager fetch

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eager-loading

I have the next class:

```
@Entity
public class Task{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Task> childs;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Task parent;
}
```

Which by default has Eager loading if I'm not wrong, the question is as follows:

What will happen when I try to load the last task if I have a lineal tree with a big number of task and everyone is child of his predecessor? Will it eagerly load all the task in the tree?

e.g:

```
Task 1; //parent of 2
Task 2; //parent of 3
.
.
.
Task n-1; //parent of n
Task n;   //parent of n+1
```

If I load n, which eagerly will load n-1, makes n-1 eagerly load n-2 and so on?

Comment: Yes.  If you have an eager relationship that connects your entire tree, the entire tree will be loaded.

Comment: Thanks!, I will have to change it to Lazy guess.